# ngx-formly textarea matTextareaAutosize

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-formly

I'm trying to figure out how to get the textarea to auto resize using matTextareaAutosize in ngx-formly. It works if I add it to the HTML as below

```
<textarea matInput matTextareaAutosize></textarea>
```

I have tried to add to the field object and also templateOptions

```
    {
      key: 'something',
      type: 'textarea',
      templateOptions: {
        label: 'Something'
      },
      matTextareaAutosize: true,
    }

    or

    {
      key: 'something',
      type: 'textarea',
      templateOptions: {
        label: 'Something',
        matTextareaAutosize: true
      }
    }
```

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: if not build in, I think custom template may be the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment of this post, the `matTextareaAutosize` property is not build in.

It is very easy to create a custom template. The component look like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FieldType } from '@ngx-formly/material';
import { MatInput } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  template: `
    <textarea matInput
              [id]="id"
              [formControl]="formControl"
              [errorStateMatcher]="errorStateMatcher"
              [cols]="to.cols"
              [rows]="to.rows"
              [placeholder]="to.placeholder"
              [formlyAttributes]="field"
              [matTextareaAutosize]="true"
    >
    </textarea>
  `
})

export class TextareaAutoResizeComponent extends FieldType implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(MatInput) formFieldControl: MatInput;
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Then define a const for type configuration:

```
export const textAreaAutoResizeType = {
  name: 'textarea-auto-resize',
  component: TextareaAutoResizeComponent,
  wrappers: ['form-field']
};
```

Finally, register the type in module:

```
imports: [
    FormlyModule.forRoot({
      types: [textAreaAutoResizeType]
    })
  ],
```

Use it like this in components:

```
{
    key: 'note',
    type: 'textarea-auto-resize',
    templateOptions: {
       label: 'Note'
    }
},
```